# Wrap content like text inside a page?

Tags: kendo-ui, scrollview, kendo-mobile

I've created a scrollview with some pages. Inside the first page there's something like :

> A very very long text which cannot be in the screen, [...]

But the text does not fit in the whole screen, it looks like this :

[image: The problem]

If I disable the scrollview :

[image: No problem when scrollview disabled]

Do you have any idea how I can wrap the content of a page to fit the screen ?

Comment: Can you embed the pic inside the question? Image shack is blocked for me. Also it will be easy for us to offer you a solution if you can post your code as a sFiddle.

Comment: I added the pic but I also find an answer. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it.

Kendo UI has in its CSS (for the Scrollview) :

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

But you can't change it because it'll broke all the scrollview.
You must change your div-page like this :

```
<div data-role="page" style="white-space : normal;">
    <p>SOME VERY LONG TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Make this for every page you want to be wrapped (very useful for small screen like iPhone)